# Tumblr audio posts don't work with infinite scroll

Tags: audio, blogs, tumblr, infinite-scroll

First of all, I have no idea about html codes, I tried to find an easy fix for my problem, but I can't understand any of them in here. I recently uploaded a new theme for my blog, but when I choose the infinite scroll option, the audio posts don't work. It just says Flash 9 is required. Please help me to fix it with some easy explanation. 
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You need to 'repair' audio posts in the Infinite Scroll callback. You'll need to go into the HTML or JS and manually fix this yourself.

[Tumblr Audio & Video + Infinite Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404807/tumblr-audio-video-infinite-scroll/12481862#12481862)